# fake path error in Jquery ajax file upload in asp.net

Tags: jquery

What is the Fake path error?? I am getting this error in my project...

```
public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler {

  public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string path = context.Request["path"];
    string filepath = Path.GetFileName(path);
    var file = context.Request.Files;

    FileInfo Fn = new FileInfo(path);
    Fn.CopyTo(context.Server.MapPath("~/upload/"+Fn.Name));
```

When ever i try to upload from file upload it saying c:/fakepath/Untitled.jpg not found!!! I tried again by creating a folder called fakepath in c drive and added Utitled.jpg file to there...Then it uploaded to my project folder(upload)... What is the issue here with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the uploadify plugin while dealing with this type of requirements.

Tutorial: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Asynchronous-File-Upload-with-jQuery-Uploadify-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```js
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();
                
reader.onload = function(e) {
$('#img_place').attr('src', e.target.result);
  }
                            
 reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
   }
  }

 $("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type='file' id="imgInp"  />
<div>
<img src="MCD402.jpg" alt="image show here" id="img_place" width="400px" height="250px">
<div>
```

Comment: How is your answer related to the question?